# PHP GD not rendering unicode fonts properly

Tags: php, gd

I am having problems in rendering unicode glyphs ( language : Malayalam, Tamil and Hindi) with PHP GD library. Is this something related to the rendering engine of GD library? Any workarounds available ?

Comment: No one around for some help ?

Comment: Look at my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21188046/writing-hindi-fonts-with-gd-library-do-not-render-as-desired/27502129#27502129

Answer (score 3):

First make sure your fonts contain the desired glyphs (system fonts such as Arial should). Then make sure you convert your parameters to unicode using `utf8_decode()` if neccessary.

Answer (score 2):

i have found one try this

```
<?php
//error_reporting(0);
$text = ("Unreadable text");
$font = "mangal.ttf";
$fontSize = "10";
$width = '600';
    $s = new CairoImageSurface(CairoFormat::ARGB32, $width, 21);
    $c = new CairoContext($s);

    /* Set the background*/
    $c->setSourceRGB(.1,149,.58);
    $c->paint();

    $c->setSourceRGB(.1,.1,.1);

    /* Make a Pango layout, set the font, then set the layout size */
    $l = new PangoLayout($c);
    $desc = new PangoFontDescription("mangal normal $fontSize");
    $l->setFontDescription($desc);

    /* Here, we use Pango markup to make part of the text bold */
    $l->setText($text);

    /* Draw the layout on the surface */
    $l->showLayout($c);
    $s->writeToPng("unicode.png");
    echo $img = "<img src=\"unicode.png\">";        
?>
```

Comment: The link in answer is not reachable anymore