# no one answered php imagettftext issue about unicode rendering

Tags: php, unicode, fonts, rendering, imagettftext

I am having a html form text input and php script to convert that sinhala language text to an image file using imagettftext(). but some characters are not rendered properly..
I have used the very same unicode font...

this is my php script;

```
imagefttext($im, 11, 0, 5, 5, $black, 'iskolapotha.ttf', $POST['testinginput']);
```

[please see this link to see the issue](http://chordshub.com/uni.png)

can anyone help me. .!
thanks in advance ! :)

Answer (score 3):

GD does not support Complex Text Rendering (for Arabic, Indic etc). If you need this, you will have to use a separate library, such as Pango ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278787/php-gd-not-rendering-unicode-fonts-properly)).

Comment: Got it ... Thank you sir... :)